# mysql repair threads not spawned

Tags: multicore, mysql

In my `my.cnf` I specify

> myisam_repair_threads=4

When I add an index to large table in the `show processlist` I see that mysql outputs:

```
 Repair with 2 threads |
 ALTER TABLE arman.files
 ADD INDEX (md5sum)
```

Why mysqld does not use more than 2 cores are there more tweaks in configfile to use more cores?

thanks Arman.

PS
I am using mysql 5.5.14

Comment: I have the exact same situation, but using MariaDB 5.2.8. Did you find the answer?

Comment: I think it can only use 1 thread per index. Perhaps your table only has 2 indexes?

Comment: table has one index, and it should be generated in parallel, atleast quick-sort should spawn multiple threads.